# How does container approach really works on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I am developing an app and initially I wanted to make sure I understand correctly container paradigm in React before doing any further development.

I understand that container component or smart component is more like a data handler, no representation here. While a dump Component is just a stateless component that is mostly the UI.

An example so far what I have, currently my index.js looks as below:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={AppComponent}/>
                <Route exact path="/products" component={ListProductComponent} />
                <Route path="/products/:productId" component={AddProductComponent} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Container Component:

```
class ProductContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.fetchProducts = this.fetchProducts.bind(this)
    }

    fetchProducts = () => {
        this.props.dispatch(fetchProductsBegin());
        getSitesApi.getAll(1)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data) {
                    this.props.dispatch(fetchProductsSuccess(response.data._embedded.companies));
                } else {
                    this.props.dispatch(fetchProductsFailure({message: "Fetching products failed"}));
                }
            });
    };

     addProduct = () => {

     };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchProducts();
    }

    render() {
        const {products} = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="ProductComponent">
                <h2>ProductComponent</h2>
                <Button color="danger" onClick={this.fetchProducts}>Load Products</Button>
                <ListProductComponent products={products}/>
                <AddProductComponent/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const productSelector = createSelector(
    state => state.products,
    items => items,
    loading => loading,
    error => error,
);

const mapStateToProps = createSelector(
    productSelector,
    (products) => ({
        products,
    })
);

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProductContainer);
```

Dump Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import './product.style.scss';
import LoadingBar from "../LoadingStatus/loading.component";

const ListProductComponent = (props) => (
    <div className="ListProductComponent">
        <h2>ListProductComponent</h2>
        <LoadingBar loading={props.products.loading}/>
        <div>
            <ul>
                {
                    props.products.items.map((item, index) =>
                        <li key={index}>{item.name}</li>
                    )
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
);

export default ListProductComponent
```

Another dump component:

```
import React from 'react';
import './product.style.scss';

const AddProductComponent = (props) => (
    <div className="AddProductComponent">
        <h2>AddProductComponent</h2>
    </div>
);

export default AddProductComponent
```

First of all, I am not sure in the router in index.js do I have to pass always container components or dump components in the component attribute. Secondly do I need to have for each list products, add product a separate containers? Since currently I am having a single product container that would for ex do the crud operations. One thing that this makes me confusing is that if I only want to show add product dump component, how can I do this? or show only list products?

I am not sure if I understand correctly the objective of containers, can anyone show a good example why would I go with container approach over normal way?

Comment: When you need local state and/or lifecycle methods you go with class-based (smart components/containers) If not then a simple functional component (dumb component not dump) will do... Router doesn't care if it's a smart or dumb component...

Comment: @SakoBu do I need to have separate smart component for both fetsh and add produtcs? is it possible to have a single product smart component that handles all crud? but then how do I decide if I only want add product component to show or list of products. kinda confusing for me

Comment: Generally speaking, it is considered best practice to make the components as small, generic and reusable as possible... The rest depends on your use case... If you are going to be using redux or not etc...

Comment: Does that mean I should have a ListProductContainer that only fetches products, AddProductContainer just to add Product? For me this looks a bit of too much having to separate behaviours of one entitity into multiple files... really having a single method just for fetching products as a separate component?

Comment: Will it work if you don’t? Probably... I just gave you what’s considered best practice... the rest is up to you...

Comment: @SakoBu it won't for sure in my case, I was just wondering if I am doing something wrong. Thou separating the crud operations in multiple files kinda seems strange for me and feels too much components ending up.

Comment: The whole idea about having smart component is to reduce the state connection with as fever components as possible, and also separate the logic from the view representation. But if I am to make for each crud operation in a separate component than I still end up state connected to many components, I cant just think of a smart comopnent that has more than one child dump component so that makes more sense for me. In my case I cant just have one smart component that has listproduct and add product childs, so all listcomponet, add component have their own smart component.